# How to make touch up paint less visible on gray car?

Tags: paint, paint-scratches, paint-clearcoat

I used to have a red car and whenever I had small scratches, I could paint over it and it would be nearly invisible. Now I've got a gray car and when I paint over a scratch it's much more visible afterwards. I've noticed that other people with gray cars also have the same problem.

Any idea why it seems to affect gray cars more than red ones? Is there anything that can be done to improve the result?

My method is to apply two layers of touch-up paint (waiting 30 min between both), then 24 hours later apply two layers of clear coat (30 min again between each application). I use this particular brand: https://www.amazon.fr/dp/B01N7XLIIN

Comment: Matching the colour is one issue, another is down to skill, preparation and application...